# Change filter on click event vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to change the filter by changing the filterKey on a click event, is this possible? Or is there a better way to achieve this?

```
<a href="#" v-on:click="filterKey = 'all'">All</a>
<a href="#" v-on:click="filterKey = 'nearby'">Nearby</a>

<ul v-for="user in users | filterBy filterKey">
    <li>{{user.name}}</li>
</ul>

data () {
    return {
        filterKey: 'all',
        users: users,
    }
},

filters: {
    all: (users) => {
        return users
    },
    nearby: (users) => {
        return users.filter((users) => {
            return users.distance <= 15
        })
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you only have two filters or do you plan on adding more? It really depends on how flexible you need it to be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use computed properties if you'd like to use an approach similar to what you have. You could do something like:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    userFilterKey: 'all',
    users: [
      { name: 'Bill Close', distance: 10 },
      { name: 'Bill Far', distance: 100 },
      { name: 'Bill Criswell', distance: 1 }
    ]
  },
  computed: {
    userFilter() {
      return this[this.userFilterKey]
    },
    all() {
      return this.users
    },
    nearby() {
      return this.users.filter((user) => user.distance <= 15)
    }
  }
})
```

Then your template can look something like this:

```
<div id="app">
  <button v-on:click="userFilterKey = 'all'" :class="{ active: userFilterKey == 'all' }">All</button>
  <button v-on:click="userFilterKey = 'nearby'" :class="{ active: userFilterKey == 'nearby' }">Nearby</button>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="user in userFilter">
      {{ user.name }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here's a demo of this in action: https://jsfiddle.net/1f9ytasb/

Though, if you plan on filtering by multiple things it might be easier to create an array of filter critera and just have one `filtered` computed property that filters out users based on that array of criteria.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!